# How can an declare an array in a function that returns an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, declaration

// functions that converts a number into an array

```
int *initialiser(int number)
{
    int array[20];

    for (int i = 19; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        array[i] = number % 10;
        number /= 10; // number = number/10
    }

    return array;
}
```

//I get this error

```
primaryAddSub.cpp: In function 'int* initialiser(int)':
primaryAddSub.cpp:21:9: warning: address of local variable 'array' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     int array[20];
         ^~~~~
```

I can use static int array[20]; but the function will return the same result each time I call it.

Comment: Use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: thanks and how can i return this type please?

Comment: `std::array<int, 20> initialiser(int number)`

Comment: or `std::vector<int> initialiser(int number) { std::vector<int> array(20); ... }` and the rest would work too. Only the call site would perhaps need some adjustment - depending on what it looks like now.

Comment: Arrays are always passed by reference, and since the array goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the function, it is impossible to return an array. You have to use something else.

Comment: When you wrote the signature `int *initialiser(int number);` you also noticed that the extent of the array is not returned (since the array has decayed into a pointer). That's yet another reason to look at alternatives, like in the answer below.

Comment: @user4581301 *Arrays are always passed by reference* WAT???  Arrays decay to a pointer and that pointer is passed by value.  To pass an array by reference, you need to explicitly do so like `void foo(int (&x)[100]);`

Comment: I dumbed down the wording a bit too much and walked into a terminology collision, but passing an object via a pointer is still pass by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says, prefer to use a `std::vector` instead of an `int*`. An example of how this works would be:

```
std::vector<int> initialiser(int number)
{
    std::vector<int> array;

    // ... fill up array

    return array;
}
```

If you absolutely want to return an `int*`, then as the error says, you are returning a pointer to a local variable. You need to allocate memory instead:

```
int *initialiser(int number)
{
    int *array = new int[20];

    // ... fill up array 

    return array;
}
```

**Don't forget** to `delete` this memory when you are done with it. Also, the caller really has no way to know *how many* elements are in the array, so they might read/write out of bounds.

In general this is error prone, so prefer the first version, then you don't have to worry about deleting anything, and are less likely to make out of bounds errors.

Comment: you are a life and time saver thanks alot....it took me hours but I didn,t find any solution.
Thanks again

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Please do take the suggestion about using `vector` instead, even if the array version is working now for you.